# Communication to PHP/MySQL server - Correct timezone

Tags: php, android, mysql, timezone

I send data from Android via HTTP Post to a Server running PHP and mysql.
The Android users share messages via this infrastructure.

I have following problem:
I want to display day and time of the messages. But I am not sure how to do that correctly.
If I set the time/date via PHP (date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s')), I have always the timezone which I have configured on my PHP server. But a guy posting a message from an other timezone, will see the wrong time or even the wrong date of his own post.

So I think the Android App must send the time + timezone to the server. In Android I can get the timezone via:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
```

So I can send the date/time and timezone via HTTP nameValuePairs to the PHP server.
But I am not sure what to do on the PHP site to store it correctly in mysql DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can use `gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s')` to set the UTC time in the server, then convert it back to the clients timezone with something like

```
public static String convertToLocalTime(String UTCtime) {

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date;
    try {
        date = df.parse(UTCtime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM");
    DateFormat timeStringPart = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma");
    return df.format(date)+", "+timeStringPart.format(date).toLowerCase();

}
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be good. But your code is crashing with a classCastException java.util.Date on Android.

Answer (score 2):

Store your dates as GMT then translate them in Android.

Comment: Can you give a hint how to do that

Comment: I think your 'tz' will have a value for GMT offset. Just adjust the date in your (android) client before you send it to the server. Do the reverse when you subsequently read the value back.

Answer (score 0):

Good rule of thumb is to have your backend store everything in UTC/GMT with offsets (MySQL does this automatically for you if your server's timezone is UTC/GMT.

Then in your frontend you can adjust all times based off the user's locale.

Comment: You mean the php server sets the time and on android I adjust it to users local timezone?

Comment: Something like that, yes. For example, if you store the time as 01:00 UTC, then you can display it in the device's timezone. So GMT-7 would be 14:00 the previous day, GMT+3 would be 04:00 the same day. Etc.